# How to choose a model for this cross-validation curve?

Tags: model-selection, gridsearchcv

I'm using GridSearchCV to tune hyperparameters for a Logistic Regression multiclass model.

I read on Kaggle that you should choose the hyperparameter that results in the lowest discrepancy between the CV-score and the training score, but in this case this leads to a very low score.

How should I choose the proper C value to ensure generalisability of the model but also high model performance based on the CV-curve below?

[image]

From my understanding opting for low discrepency between the two scores ensures the ability of the model to be generalised to unseen data. But on the other hand I want a score as high as possible on unseen data.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the best validation accuracy is the common practice, since validation is unseen data.

Sometimes you might have over-fitting to the validation set, mainly if it is too small or no very representative of the data (for example if it has considerably more examples of one class, thus a good model would be a model that says that (almost) everything belongs to that class).

If you are worried about over-fitting, you could increase your regularization strength.

Comment: I do have a small validation set, that's not completely balanced, Thank you for your answer. I'm going for a bit lower C value.